# how to display entered letter in c?

Tags: c, for-loop

I am new to `c programming`. I have created a program for entered letters and finally displayed the entered letters.. but it displayed only final letters always.. please help .. i know its simple question but am beginner so please help guys..

```
 #include<stdio.h>      
    int main()
    {
        char z;
        int a;
            printf("enter the no.");
            scanf("%d",&a);
            printf("the entered no. is:%d\n",a);
            int i;
            for(i=0;i<a;i++)
            {
                printf("enter the letters:");
                scanf("%s",&z);
            }
            printf("the entered letters are:");
            for(i=0;i<a;i++)
            {
                printf("%s\n",&z);
            }
            return 0;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems:

1. You should use `%c` (for character) instead of `%s` (for string).
2. Use a character array for storing multiple characters. Read about arrays [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/).
3. Remove `&` from `printf()` in the second `for` loop.

Try this:

```
int main()
{
    char z[10];  //can hold 10 characters like z[0],z[1],z[2],..
    int a;
    printf("enter the no.");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("the entered no. is:%d\n",a);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        printf("enter the letters:");
        scanf("%c",&z[i]);
    }
    printf("the entered letters are:");
    for(i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        printf("%c\n",z[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks bro but i want to print the entered letter only ..it displayed all the letters like triangle

Comment: The array can hold upto 10 characters only. If you want more than that, change the array size. `it displayed all the letters like triangle`? I didn't get that.

Comment: if i entered the letters like a b c d e f g h i                    output is like abcdefghi abcdefgh abcdefg abcdef abcde likewise but line by line .

Comment: First, set the limit (value of `a` which is <10), then enter each letter. When limit reaches , `scanf` will stop. Then in next `for` loop, it will print each letter you have entered.

Comment: please edit my code bro till i didnt gt any sollution

Comment: @R.A: Just copy this code and paste it in your project, my friend.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1928264/raging-bull  if i gv 3 as input and then enter letter a . it wont ask for nxt letter its just showed the output is a.. but i want to give 3 letters and display that 3 letters finally.. friend you just try your code you can get any idea to change the code please..

Comment: Have you replaced your code with mine? Note that I have removed the `&` in the second `for` loop.

Comment: ya friend i have only copied ur code and execute that .. it only shows that type of output what i said in previous comment..

Answer (score 2):

Letters are scanned using `%c`. And to scan multiple letters you can use `char` array: `char z[10];`

What you are trying to do can be done this way:

```
        char z[10];   // Take some max size array
        ...
        for(i=0;i<a;i++)
        {
            printf("enter the letters:");
            scanf("%c",&z[i]);    // Scan the letters on each array position.
        }
        printf("the entered letters are:");
        for(i=0;i<a;i++)
        {
            printf("%c\n",z[i]);  //'printf' doesn't require address of arg as argument hence no `&` required
        }
```

`%s` argument is used to scan a string of `chars`.

Note the difference between *string* of `chars` and *array* of `chars`. The string of `chars` in C needs to be terminated with ASCII Character `0` represented as `\0` in `char` format, while the array of char is just a collection of letters which need not be terminated with `\0`.

The difference becomes more important when you try to perform some operation on strings such as `printf`, `strcpy`, `strlen`, etc.. These functions work on null character termination property of string.

For Example: `strlen` counts the characters in the string till it finds `\0`, to find out the length of string. Similarly, `printf` prints the string character by character until it finds the `\0` character.

**UPDATE:**

Forgot to mention that `scanf` is not a good option to input `char` format. Use `fgetc` instead, with `stdin` as input FILE stream.

Comment: please edit my code bro till i didnt gt any sollution

Answer (score 2):

`char z` is a place holder for one character only. And you are over writing what you set `z` to in the `for` loop. To take in more characters, use a `char array` as others have mentioned.

Or print the characters in the same you loop you are scanning them:

```
#include<stdio.h>      
int main()
{
    char z;
    int a;
    printf("enter the no.");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("the entered no. is:%d\n",a);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
         printf("enter the letters:");
         scanf("%s",&z);
         printf("letter scanned:%c\n", z);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please edit my code bro till i didnt gt any sollution

Comment: friend its not right .. i will explained clearly what i want.. if i gv the input as 4 after that the 4 is passed to for loop and ask for enter the 4 letters .. after i entered the four letters .. it will display with new line .. but your code is if i gv a,it shows a at a time .. but i dont want like that friend .. can u understand my words?

Comment: Yes, I do. If you clearly read my answer, it says that you can't do what you are trying to do using a `char` variable. Either use an `array` as others have suggested or print the variables as & when you are reading them. Hope you have a better understanding now.

Answer (score 2):

Please look into [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) for more details on scanf. You have given `scanf("%s",&z);`  `%s` is for reading strings(array of chars except newline char and ended with `null` char). So if you put this inside loop you wont get desired result. And if you want read only a char at a time use `%c` here c for Character.

```
for(i=0;i<a;i++)
{
            printf("enter the letters:");
            scanf("%c",z+i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>      

int main()
{
    char *z;
    int a;
    printf("enter the no.");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    z = (char *) malloc(a);
    printf("the entered no. is:%d\n",a);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        printf("enter the letters:");
        scanf("%c",z+i);
    }
    printf("the entered letters are:");
    for(i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        printf("%c\n",z);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please edit my code bro till i didnt gt any sollution

Answer (score 1):

first error in your code is you have used "%s" instead of "%c".Second is it is impossible to store multiple values in one variable so instead of using variable use arrays.third is that you have told the user to enter the number of character that he/she wants to entered which you don't know.They can enter 1 also and 100000 also so the number of members in array is not defined.Better is to use specific number of characters in array.

Answer (score 0):

finally i got the answer thank you for the help stackoverflow guys simply rocks ...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
int main()
{
        int a;
        char *z=(char *)malloc(sizeof(a));  
        printf("enter the no.");
        scanf("%d",&a);
        printf("the entered no. is:%d\n",a);
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<a;i++)
        {
            printf("enter the letters:");
            scanf("%s",&z[i]);
        }
        printf("the entered letters are:\n");
        for(i=0;i<a;i++)
        {                
            printf("%c\n",z[i]);
        }
        return 0;

}
```